# How to include subsection titles next to the bullets with the singapore beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, themes, mini-frames

I am using `Singapore` theme in [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) and I would like to have the title of the subsections appearing next to the corresponding bullets, in the header. Would anyone have a suggestion on how to proceed ? I am a rather naive LaTeX user...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Singapore style loads the outertheme `miniframes` with the option `subsection=false`.  To change this you have to turn on an internal variable in beamer by running the command `\beamer@theme@subsectiontrue`.  As this name includes the sign `@` you need to enclose this in a `\makeatletter / \makeatother` pair as below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}
\makeatletter
\beamer@theme@subsectiontrue
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
  Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Wow, much better, thanks a lot (and thanks for the explanations :-) ) ! That could do the trick... However, I had something else in mind, like, say :
subsection 1 ooo
subsection 2 oo
subsection 3 ooooo

instead of :

ooo
oo
ooooo

Would you think that would be doable ? If not, I'd be perfectly happy with your solution, anyway !
Marc

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see a simple way to do that.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for your help, it really makes a difference for me :-)